# $this->> what does this symbol means in PHP

Tags: php, laravel, syntax

> NOTE: I tried googling. But did get any reference which explains the
>   same

Hi, I came across this **->>** symbol while referring a GITHUB repo https://github.com/jsdecena/baserepo

What does that actually mean? It's not even having a __construct method. Does that mean it automatically binds to __contruct in PHP?

> Okay, I am stressing **__construct** because the private properties
>   cant call the models function directly. For that, we need to have
>   Model at lease

**If it was kind of typo than at least I was expecting __construct in the class.**

Following is the snippet of the same which is used in Laravel of the repository.

```
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Repositories\UserRepository;
use App\User;

class MyController extends Controller {

    private $userRepository;

    public function index() 
    {
        $user = $this->>userRepository->all(); /** <----- HERE THIS LINE ---- */

        return response()->json($data);    
    }
}
```

Comment: `$this->>` is incorrect and it will cause `syntax` error. It should be `$this->` when accessing any property or method.

Comment: It's a syntax error on [all PHP versions](https://3v4l.org/UQt61).

Comment: @AakashTushar I totally agree with you. But the interesting thing is I didn't find the contructor method.

Comment: @ChannaveerHakari what does it have to do with a constructor?

Comment: @deceze thanks for the link. I thought I might not know the symbol

Comment: @slepic I totally agree with you. But look at the code carefully. The **private** variable is able to call *MODEL* functions.

Comment: See how its extending Controller, Look in that model `use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;` you will see it has a constructor

Comment: @ChannaveerHakari yeah i would also prefer injecting it through constructor. But there are other means... You can modify any property (public, protected, private) from any scope you want. I wouldnt worry about it, the `->>` is syntax error no matter if there is a constructor and no matter how that property is injected....

Comment: `" private variable is able to call MODEL functions"` 

That's because `UserRepository` is extending `BaseRepository`.
check [UserRepository.php](https://github.com/jsdecena/baserepo/blob/master/src/Repositories/UserRepository.php)

Comment: @slepic thanks for **You can modify any property (public, protected, private) from any scope you want.**

Comment: @AakashTushar Ah! Good pointing. But I do have one more query please solve it. How does that private property know that it must refer that Repository class

Comment: Check Laravel's service container binding [Binding Primitives](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/container#binding-basics). You can bind a variable through service container. It must have done something like `$this->app->when(MyController::class)
          ->needs('$userRepository')
          ->give(new UserRepository);`

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I have updated the README file. Cheers guys!